# Fullscreen OSMF video player

Tags: actionscript-3, air, osmf

I'm working on a Air video player using OSMF framework -- mostly following code from here -- http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_HTTP_Streaming_in_OSMF-17636.html.

I'm struggling to find a way to have the video display fullscreen. What params should I use that have the video fit the whole screen?

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

container.width = stage.stageWidth;
container.height = stage.stageHeight;
```